# AWS - Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker

I'm trying to use Beanstalk on AWS. I'm trying to create an instance (micro) with Dockerrun.aws.json like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "coaxys/play-127",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "9080"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/var/app/mydb",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/etc/mysql"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

But after it's complete I need to run an script which I've placed in my .zip. Is this possible? I tried to create a Dockerfile but none of the images that I specify are recognised. This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Nicolas Giard, nicolas.giard@coaxys.com

# make sure the package repository is up to date
RUN echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install unzip && apt-get clean
RUN mkdir /opt/play && cd /opt/play
RUN wget http://downloads.typesafe.com/play/1.2.7/play-1.2.7.zip
RUN unzip play-1.2.7.zip
RUN mv play-1.2.7 /opt/play
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/play play /opt/play/play-1.2.7/play 1
RUN echo "PLAY_HOME=/opt/play/play-1.2.7" >> /etc/environmentRUN echo "PLAY_HOME=/opt/play/play-1.2.7" >> /etc/environment
RUN mkdir -p /opt/deploy
RUN sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.org
RUN sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Brazil/East /etc/localtime
RUN export PLAY_HOME=/opt/play
RUN export PATH=$PLAY_HOME:$PATH

EXPOSE 9080
```

Is it possible to call an executable from Dockerrun.aws.json or there is problem with my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are with the same problem, try to replace "\r\n" to "\n". Its worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue. Worked fine for boot2docker on windows, and even in a linux container - fell over once I went to AWS.